# JavaFX custom ListCell

Tags: javafx-8

I'm trying to animate ListCell when they appear.
Specially I try to animate a new cell when it was just added to the list.
For now it's working pretty OK except when I scroll the ListView, then indexes get messed up and the wrong cell is animated.
I use a boolean flag (entering) in my item model to detect when a cell is used for a brand new item.

```
    public class TimeListCell extends ListCell<MarkItem> {

    private static final String BUTTON_GOTO_MARK_CLASS = "but-markgoto";
    private static final String LABEL_TIME_MARK_CLASS = "track-time";
    private static final String BUTTON_DELETE_MARK_CLASS = "but-markdel";
    private static final String MARK_HIGHLIGHT_CURRENT_CLASS = "highlighted";

    private Instant time;

    private MarkItem markItem;

    protected ListCellAnimation anim;

    private HBox root = new HBox();
    private Button go = new Button();
    private Label track = new Label();;
    private Button del = new Button();

    private ChangeListener<? super Boolean> highlightChange = (e, o, n) -> { setHighlighted(n); };

    public TimeListCell (Consumer<MarkItem> onGoto, Consumer<MarkItem> onDelete) {

        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        go.getStyleClass().add(BUTTON_GOTO_MARK_CLASS);
        go.setOnAction( e -> {
            if (onGoto != null) {
                // Trigger GOTO consumer function
                onGoto.accept(markItem);
            }
        });
        track.getStyleClass().add(LABEL_TIME_MARK_CLASS);
        del.getStyleClass().add(BUTTON_DELETE_MARK_CLASS);
        del.setOnAction( e -> {
            // First trigger exit animation then delete item
            this.animateExit(onDelete);
        });

        root.getChildren().add(go);
        root.getChildren().add(track);
        root.getChildren().add(del);

    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem (final MarkItem item, boolean empty) {

        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (markItem != null) {
            markItem.highlightedProperty().removeListener(highlightChange);
        }

        if (!empty && item != null) {
            markItem = item;
            time = item.getTime();

            track.setText(DateUtil.format(time, DateUtil.Pattern.TIME));
            setGraphic(root);

            item.highlightedProperty().addListener(highlightChange);
            setHighlighted(item.isHighlighted());

            if (anim == null) {
                //Adding Animation to the ListCell
                anim = new ListCellAnimation(this);
                //KeyFrame[] f = getKeyFrames(types);
                KeyFrame[] frames = null;
                if (anim.getKeyFrames().size() == 0) {
                    KeyFrame[] f = anim.getPopIn(frames);
                    if (f != null) {
                        anim.getKeyFrames().addAll(f);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (item.isEntering()) {
                //Checking when to play Animation
                animateEnter();
                item.setEntering(false);
            }
        } else {
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set/unset cell highlighted style for display.
     *
     * @param   highlighted
     *              Whether or not to highlight the cell
     */
    public void setHighlighted (boolean highlighted) {

        track.getStyleClass().remove(MARK_HIGHLIGHT_CURRENT_CLASS);
        if (highlighted)
            track.getStyleClass().add(MARK_HIGHLIGHT_CURRENT_CLASS);
    }

    /**
     * Animate entering cell.
     */
    private void animateEnter() {
            if (anim != null && anim.getKeyFrames().size() >= 0
                    && (anim.getTimeline().getStatus() == Timeline.Status.STOPPED
                    || anim.getTimeline().getStatus() == Timeline.Status.PAUSED)) {
                    anim.getTimeline().playFromStart();
            }
    }

    /**
     * Animate exiting cell.
     * Trigger DELETE consumer function when animation is complete.
     */
    private void animateExit (Consumer<MarkItem> onDelete) {

        anim.getReversedTimeline().setOnFinished( t -> {
            // Remove item from list
            if (onDelete != null) {
                onDelete.accept(markItem);
            }
            // Prepare cell for next item to use it
            scaleXProperty().set(1);
            scaleYProperty().set(1);
            });
        anim.getReversedTimeline().playFromStart();
    }

    public Instant getTime () {

        return time;
    }
}
```

Has anyone any idea of what could mess up the cell indexing ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If a cell which is animating is reused to display an item that is not "entering", then you need to stop the current animation:

```
    if (item.isEntering()) {
        //Checking when to play Animation
        animateEnter();
        item.setEntering(false);
    } else {
        anim.getTimeline().stop();
    }
```

In general, you seem to be assuming that any given cell is only ever used for a single item, which is certainly not the case. There may be other bugs in your code that are consequences of this assumption, but this is the main one I can see.

Comment: Thanks James for your help.

Comment: Thanks again James.  But stopping the animation does not do any good as updateItem gets called several times for each "refresh".  Item is not "entering" anymore on subsequent calls so animation is stopped.  As a matter of fact, it is working OK the way it is now, except when item list is long and I start scrolling it.  When I scroll and one or more new cells are created at the end of the list (I know cells get reassigned to visible items), then when I add a new item in list, animation happens on the wrong cell, although the highlight operation targets the right cell...

Comment: Everything works fine before any scrolling. But when I scroll down and reveal cells (2 cells for example), then when I create a new item, the animated cell it the one 2 cells away from the one representing the created item.

Comment: @keuluu I think you also need `markItem = null ;` and to stop the timeline in the final `else` clause. You basically need to make sure that `updateItem(...)` accounts for all possible changes in the item. But you should probably create a [MCVE] as without being able to test, anyone else is just guessing.

Comment: Also tried that... I'll take time to setup a minimal example to solve this out. Thanks again for your help.